# Can I ping a v6 mapped v4 address?

Tags: ipv6

If I have an address **10.3.3.2** , mapping it to v6 will result in 0:0:0:0:0:ffff:a03:302.
I am able to ping 10.3.3.2 but pinging 0:0:0:0:0:ffff:a03:302 gives "No route to host" error. Right now, I am not able to ping any IPv6 address from within my network so the error is expected.

I am curious if
    **ping6 0:0:0:0:0:ffff:a03:302**

if IPv6 traffic was going out perfectly.

Comment: You can't simply map IPv4 addresses to IPv6 the way you seem to think. IPv4 and IPv6 are two completely separate protocols that cannot directly communicate.

Comment: The notation you use is commonly used in software that needs to represent an IPv4 address in IPv6 notation. But it's still representing an IPv4 address and can't be used as a real IPv6 address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called **NAT64** and is decribed in [RFC-6146](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6146).

You have to do some more things for this to work.

First, the mapped address must start with `64:ff9b::` (it is a reserved prefix, specifically for NAT64) instead of `0:0:0:0:0:ffff:` (this old prefix, that first appeared in late 1995, inside RFC-1884, is not used for IPv6 to IPv4 gateways - it is used to map addresses stored by networking software, for instance, but not when you want to connect to an IPv4 host through an IPv6 network).

So, mapping 10.3.3.2 to ipv6 gives `64:ff9b::a03:302`

But in the real world, nobody has to do such a weird mapping, you only have to make a DNS request for a hostname with IP address 10.3.3.2 to a resolver that is DNS64-compliant (such a DNS resolver is called a DNS64 resolver, as explained in [RFC-6147](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6147)). Google offers this one (among others): `2001:4860:4860::6464`, free of use for everybody. So, you only have to configure your DNS resolver to request this Google host (do not forget to remove any other resolver).

Note that private IPv4 addresses are not supported by Google public DNS64 resolvers. So, in your example, we need to replace 10.3.3.2 by a public address. So, I choose 1.3.3.2, that is a public address.

For you to make a test, I have created the following DNS record: `tstaupreti.fenyo.fr`, that is mapped to 1.3.3.2.

Then using `dig`, you can easily check how it works:

1- first, you can ask a standard public DNS, like 8.8.8.8 (a public DNS by Google, but not DNS64 compliant), to give an IPv4 address for this host:

```
% dig @8.8.8.8 tstaupreti.fenyo.fr. a +short
1.3.3.2
%
```

2- now, you can check there is no IPv6 address associated with the host name:

```
% dig @8.8.8.8 tstaupreti.fenyo.fr. aaaa +short
%
```

3- so, let's see what happens with the Google DNS64 resolver:

```
% dig @2001:4860:4860::6464 tstaupreti.fenyo.fr. a +short
1.3.3.2
%
```

This is normal, because we have requested the IPv4 address, and the DNS64 resolver is, of course, IPv4 compliant.

4- but now, let's see the DNS64 resolver working to compute the mapping for you:

```
% dig @2001:4860:4860::6464 tstaupreti.fenyo.fr. aaaa +short
64:ff9b::103:302
%
```

As you can see, the NAT64 Google resolver has not seen any IPv6 address associated with tstaupreti.fenyo.fr, so it tried to see if an IPv4 address was associated to this host name, it found 1.3.3.2 and, so, converted it to the NAT64 IPv6 format: **`64:ff9b::103:302`**

But this is not enough to be able to get an icmp reply when pinging tstaupreti.fenyo.fr with IPv6.

This is because you also need to have access to a **NAT64 IPv6 to IPv4 gateway** and route IPv6 packets for `64:ff9b::/96` to this NAT64 gateway. This way, whatever value the DNS64 mapping returned, your ICMP requests (ping) will go to the NAT64 gateway. And this gateway will convert your packets from IPv6 to IPv4 (more or less like a standard NAT IPv4 gateway - see the RFC for more details, there are subtle variations).

Unfortunately, NAT64 defines `64:ff9b::/96` as a reserved prefix that you can not route on the Internet (this is because this address is the same on each private network that offers a NAT64 gateway, like 10.x.x.x that is often routed on private networks, therefore, for the same reason, it must not be routed on the Internet). So, there is no public NAT64 gateway working with the NAT64 prefix `64:ff9b::/96` (you could use another prefix, and route it to a NAT64 gateway configured with this uncommon prefix, but this is another story). Some Internet Services Providers route such an address to a private NAT64 gateway dedicated to their customers. If your ISP does not do that, you need to install such a gateway yourself, on your private IPv6 network. To do that, you may use [Tayga](http://www.litech.org/tayga/) for Linux.

So, after having performed this last step (installation of Tayga, for instance), you will receive an ICMP reply from your ping request. It will work when sending ping packets to any IPv4-only server on the Internet.